# Rainbow Animated Text

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to make an animated rainbow text (left to right) so far everything was working until it reached the final of the colors list (c list) and when I try to rollback (`if x == 18: ; x = 0`) it dosent work

Please help

```
import os
import time
from sty import fg, bg, ef, rs, RgbFg

c = [196, 202, 208, 214, 220, 226, 190, 118, 121, 122, 123, 75, 33, 21, 93, 171, 201, 199]

w = "ElapsedTime"

#fg(c[0]) + w[0] + fg(c[0]) + w[1] + fg(c[0]) + w[2] + fg(c[0]) + w[3] + fg(c[0]) + w[4]

final = []
n = 0

def clear():
    time.sleep(.01)
    os.system("clear")

def d001(x):
    y = 0
    while True:
            f101 = fg(c[x]) + w[y]
            final.append(f101)
            x = x+1
            if x == 18:
                x = 0
            if y == 10:
                break
            y = y+1
    print("".join(final))
    final.clear()

while True:
    d001(n)
    print(n)
    n = n+1
    if n == 20:
        break
```

Comment: What does *it doesn't work* mean specifically?

Comment: So it goes through all the color in the list (c) by using c[x] ; x=x+1 but when it reaches the end (18) it dosent rollback when I putted x=0

Comment: So insert some `print` statements to output x and y on each pass through and see if you can figure out why that's happening. Or use the debugger to step through the code. You won't have to loop too many times to see what's going wrong. And remember for future questions that *it doesn't work* is not a problem description; you need to be very specific in describing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

X and Y both will increase by 1 and `y == 10` become true before `x == 18` and break the loop